APK Size Increased by 100 MB After Adding sqflite and path Packages in Flutter
I recently added the following packages to my Flutter project:
dependencies:
  sqflite: ^2.3.2
  path: ^1.8.3

Since adding these packages, I've noticed that my APK size has increased by approximately 100 MB, bringing the total size to around 200 MB. This is a significant increase, and I’m concerned about the impact on app performance and user experience.

What I Have Tried:

Run flutter clean: Cleared build artifacts and cached files.

Clear Flutter and Gradle Cache: Used flutter pub cache repair and deleted .gradle caches.

Analyze APK Size: Attempted to analyze the APK size but faced issues with specifying a single ABI.


Questions:

Is it common for the sqflite and path packages to cause such a large increase in APK size?

What are the possible reasons for this substantial size increase after adding these packages?

What additional steps can I take to further investigate and reduce the APK size?


Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I am not sure about sqflite and path. But here are some tips to cretae apk a bit lighter.

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build apk --release
this will create apk in release.
I hope this work for you.

